# category hierarchy with mysql

Tags: mysql, hierarchical-data

I am trying to create an hierarchy of categories in MySQL and the code that I use to create the `categories` table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `description` tinytext,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY parentid_fk (`parent_id`) 
      REFERENCES categories (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The database replies an error numbered 150. What can be done to address this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `parent_id` is same definition (I mean datatype and all) as of primary key `id` like below.

```
`parent_id` int(11) unsigned
```

Your `id` column is defined as `id int(11) unsigned`; whereas `parent_id` defined as `parent_id int(11)`.

Make `parent_id` as well `int(11) unsigned`. See a [Proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/168ef)

Comment: That's causing the problem Rahul. I was overlooking the problem because the id was generated by a tool (and I am quite new to this tool). Thanks for your help.